# Not showing input value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print the input values. I tried passing the console directly to the value retrieved from the input, I tried passing it to a function and the value still doesn't appear. I looked at some questions already posted here and apparently it was supposed to work that way but it's not working so that this value appears in the console

```js
let tasks = []

const includeTask = document.getElementById("include-task")
const listTask = document.getElementById("list-task")
const taskSelector = document.getElementById("task-selector")

const taskSelectorValue = taskSelector.value

console.log(taskSelectorValue)

function choiceFunction() {
  console.log("cheguei aqui")
  console.log(taskSelectorValue)
}

choiceFunction()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>Escolha uma das opções abaixo:
  <p id="include-task">1 - Incluir tarefa</p>
  <p id="list-task">2 - Listar tarefa</p>
  <input 
    placeholder="Insira sua escolha aqui" 
    type="text" 
    id="task-selector" 
    name="choice"/>

  <button onclick="choiceFunction()">Escolher</button>
 
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `const taskSelectorValue = taskSelector.value` is running when the code initially loads, not when you click. If you want that value to be calculated on click, that line needs to be in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

The taskSelectorValue variable is assigned the value of taskSelector.value immediately when the script is loaded. This means it will always be an empty string because the input field is empty at that point.

Move the task selector const inside the function

```
function choiceFunction() {
  const taskSelectorValue = taskSelector.value;
  console.log("cheguei aqui");
  console.log(taskSelectorValue);
```